# Why does youtube-dl raise the bitrates of M4A files when it transcodes them?

Tags: windows, audio, command-line, cmd.exe, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download videos from a YouTube playlist using [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl). When downloading a sample of 25 videos from the playlist with:

`youtube-dl -x -i --playlist-items 1-25 -f bestaudio <playlist URL here>`

...I get the audio in assorted filetypes, with the bitrate of the files ranging from 126-178.

However, when I download the same 25 videos using:

`youtube-dl -x -i --playlist-items 1-25 --audio-format m4a <playlist URL here>`

...which transcodes the extracted audio files to `.M4A` format, all the transcoded files (which were previously either `.OPUS` or `.OGG` and between 128-178kbps) are suddenly much larger, ranging from 341-440kbps.

I must have gone through `youtube-dl`'s man page a hundred times, but I couldn't find anything that would explain this behaviour. So what exactly's going on here? Why does `youtube-dl` raise the bitrates of audio files when it transcodes them to M4A format? Is this expected behaviour, or a youtube-dl quirk?

Comment: I can't answer this for sure, but it's probably increasing the bitrate of the output to try to minimise the loss of quality associated with transcoding.

Comment: But why would it feel the need to do that - does upscaling the bitrate after a transcode actually provide any real gain? I was always under the impression that bitrate is set largely independent of format, and that whatever it's set at increasing it artifically would make no real difference to the actual quality of the file.

Comment: It actually could depending on the sample rate and quantization and whenever those match up or not. If I'm not mistaken m4a is also just a container format so you'd have to look at the actual details of the codec used. Depending on what you used to read the bitrate it might also be an error in said program. Some programs to have issues with VBR encoding an would display the highest bitrate.